# Cannot use greater than and replace year

Tags: r, lubridate

I cannot able to replace the year greater than with another value which results in below year. Please help me replacing the year with greater than symbol.

Code

```
library(lubridate)
x <- ymd("2012-03-26")
year(x) > 1995 =2013

RESULT:
Error in year(x) > 1995 = 2001 : could not find function "><-"
```

Expected output

```
>x
"2001-03-26"
```

Comment: What is your expected output? Do you want to change 2012 to 2001?

Comment: Are you saying that in your example, year 2012 is greater that 1995, and you want to replace that year 2012 by 2001? and it will return 2001-03-26? Please clarify further

Comment: Try this: `ifelse(year(x) > 1995, gsub(year(x), "2001",x)) `. Can change it back to ymd.

Comment: yes @YonP and NelsonGon to replace the year to 2001-03-26

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to set a condition (`year(x) > 1995`)  to a value. This is just a  logical vector of TRUE and FALSE values which in your example would just be TRUE.

You want to actually be setting elements of `x` to a value `x[year(x) > 1995]`.

```
year(x[year(x) > 1995] ) <- 2001
x
[1] "2001-03-26"
```

Answer (score 2):

First, your error is `All formats failed to parse. No formats found` because that is not a date string. That is called a datetime since it has `00:00:00`. Since `ymd` is only for dates, use `ymd_hms`.

Now, I'm not sure if you still want those `00:00:00` after you change the year so if yes, then

`ifelse(year(ymd_hms(date)) > 1995, format(ymd_hms(date), "2001-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), date)`

Comment: This is all true but it's not a response to the question actually asked, it's a response to a comment.

Answer (score 1):

We can achieve the expected output by utilising `base` ifelse:

```
  ymd(ifelse(year(x) > 1995, gsub(year(x), "2001",x),x))
[1] "2001-03-26"
```

For a vector of dates:

```
sapply(ymd(years), function(yr) ifelse(year(yr) > '1995', 
                                      gsub(year(yr), '2001',yr),yr))
```

Data:

```
years <- rep(x, 4)
```

Comment: it gives the following error when i replace it in my original ```> date1 <-  ymd(ifelse(year(date) > '1995', gsub(year(date), '2001',date),date))
                                    Warning messages:
1: In gsub(year(date), "2001", date) :
  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: All formats failed to parse. No formats found. ```

Comment: Is your actual data in a data frame or as it is in the question? Could you add a dput that reflects what the data looks like? Otherwise you probably need to replace `gsub` with a "more powerful(more vectorised)" function like those from `stringr`.

Comment: its in a vector form @NelsonGon ```> head(date)
[1] "1998-08-07 00:00:00" "1986-11-15 00:00:00" "1984-08-23 00:00:00" "1986-07-05 00:00:00" "1986-07-16 00:00:00"
[6] "1978-11-07 00:00:00"```

Comment: Please take a look at the edit and see if it works.

Comment: @prog This is really totally changing the question. If you have a question about that separate error message then you should really post that separately.